# SignalR preventing axios calls (Pending State)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core-signalr

I am currently working on a project which has a feature to bid on product available in Auctions. And for the same we need realtime update's of bid price.

As there can be thousand or lacs of user from worldwide, who will be bidding.

So, we have used SignalR for RealTime Update's but the problem is when more than 3 connections are connected then not able to connect more users and also if we refresh the page then the enpoints/api called using Axios goes into pending state and doesn't return the data until the other user from another system doesn't refresh the page.

If multiple users are using the website at the same time then more than 3 connections are not created and api's using axios goes into pending state and in queue when one connection is released then only previous apis are completed.

Below is the code used on ReactJS end for SignalR

```
const getUpcomingLots = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {

      let hubConnectionBuilder: any = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(HUBURL, {
          headers: {
            "Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy": "*",
          },
          withCredentials: false,
        })
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

      hubConnectionBuilder.start().then(() => {
        hubConnectionBuilder.on("SendUpcomingLots", (data: any) => {
          setUpcomingLots(data);
        });


        axios
          .get(`${APIURL}?auctionId=${ID}&customerId=${customerId}`)
          .then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.log("APIURL Error Send", new Date());
          });
      });
      
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed, I am stuck with this issue more than a week and we need to make the website live next week.

I already tried many solutions but no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We recommend that you use the free trial of `Azure SignalR Service` to see if the number of connections can exceed 3 connections.

Comment: If you use Azure Signalr Service and the results are still not achieved, we recommend that you enable [front logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript-client-logging) and [backend logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-8.0#server-side-logging).

Comment: [Live trace tool also could help us to check more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-live-trace)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, would like to answer my own question here.

So, the solution was to deploy the backend code on VM OS Server, as previously the backend was on IIS Server deployed on Windows 10 which by default has limitation of 10 concurrent connections.

Deploying backend on VM OS Server, resolved the issue as it can handle unlimited concurrent connections.

Would like to appreciated everyone who commented.